# Measuring latency to a firewalled server

Tags: networking, ping, latency

The firewall in front of this server is blocking ping requests. Is is still possible to measure latency to this system? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like [tcpping](http://www.vdberg.org/~richard/tcpping.html) to measure the latency of TCP connections (assuming you have at least one open port to talk to).